# Sencha Touch 2.2: list items render on top of each other in android phonegap app

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm experiencing this weird issue where on every third launch or so of my sencha touch 2.2 android phonegap app all my list items render on top of each other. As soon as you drag the list a bit it sorts itself out.

Tried a bunch of things: changing all configs on my list, removing all my custom css, adding a scroll function that scrolls down and then up again after the list has finished rendering, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Update: Better description of the setup.

The list is inside of a navigationview which, in turn, is inside a slidenavigationview (github.com/wnielson/sencha-SlideNavigation).

The store is set on initialization of the list view.

List definition (a little bit simplified):

```
Ext.define('Labblistan.view.LabList', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
xtype: 'lablist',
requires: [
    'Labblistan.controller.SearchController',
    'Ext.util.DelayedTask',
    'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
    'Ext.SegmentedButton'],

id: 'lablist',
config: {
    grouped: true,
    infinite: true,
    useSimpleItems: true,
    variableHeights: true,
    plugins: [{
        xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefresh',
        pullRefreshText: 'Dra ned för att uppdatera!',
        lastUpdatedText: 'Senast uppdaterad',
        loadingText: 'Förbereder uppdatering',
        releaseRefreshText: 'Släpp för att uppdatera!',
        refreshFn: function (plugin) {
            confirmUpdate();
        }
    }],
    itemTpl: itemtemplate, //long and kinda complicated so I didn't include it here
    onItemDisclosure: true,
    disableSelection: true,
    indexBar: {
        right: '-10px'
    },
    loadingText: 'Laddar',
    iconmask: true,
    scrollToTopOnRefresh: false,
    cls: 'listan',
    items: items, //Contains another toolbar with some buttons for improved sorting
    listeners: {
        initialize: function () {
            console.log('initialize list');
            var dynstore = Ext.getStore('LabListStore');
            this.setStore(dynstore);
        },
        painted: function () {
            console.log('painted list');
            setTimeout(function () {
                Ext.getCmp('listbar').enable();
            }, 600);
            Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
            return false;
        },
        hide: function () {
            console.log('hide list');
            return false;
        }
    }
}
});
```

[image]

Comment: Could you share some code? This happens in desktop browser too?

Comment: Unfortunately can't test in desktop browser because of cordova code. Does not happen on iOS though. What code would be helpful? The list conf? Will add that now + extended description of the setup

Comment: I already had some weird bugs with phonegap. If works fine in IOS I suggest first you try to use another version of phonegap (can be a older one, only to test). I cant see any problem in your sencha code, so can be phonegap or some plugins you are using. Only put your "id" inside your config, all configs now have to be inside the config object (outside config is deprecated). I had trouble with that too (created a very weird problem after sencha compiler).

Comment: Thanks, as I'm on 2.6 now I'll start out by upgrading to 2.7 and see if it makes a difference. Oh, and moved id, thanks!

Comment: Could you share the CSS linked to your list. Everything related to .listan

Comment: I had similar issue and it was sorted by fixing template's CSS, so please try giving height to `div`s in your template.

Comment: @TDeBailleul Haven't got any css for listan (used to but have removed it, I am setting dislay:none on the disclosure icon though and setting the font-size to 12pt

Comment: @ThinkFloyd Tried adding height, but to no avail, also I need variable height of my items (disabling that does not help though)

Comment: @Scoup Upgrading CDV unfortunately didn't help

Comment: I'm without ideas... Try to add layout: "fit" in the config to force use all space.

Comment: thanks @Scoup but unfortunately this didn't do the trick either. I'm gonna try posting in the sencha forums as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you've upgraded your app to Sencha 2.2 (rather than generated a new one), something might have gotten mucked up in the upgrading of app.css (it was when I upgraded). Lists were revamped heavily in Sencha 2.2, so the CSS from pre-2.2 breaks the lists.

If you replace the unsuccessfully upgraded app.css with the app.css that's created from a new Sencha 2.2 app (`sencha app generate`), that should fix the problem, or at least it did for me. If that doesn't work, adding:

```
.x-list .x-list-item{
    position: relative !important;
}
```

should work.

Hope that's helpful!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me, instead it adds a whole new problem with items getting successively taller when scrolling. Screenshot: http://i44.tinypic.com/zl88xu.png

Comment: Perhaps try looking at the CSS and removing the natural padding/margins/decreasing the hight of .x-list-item?

Comment: Are you referring to ST 2.2's own default css or any custom css I might have?

Comment: Both. Inspect element in Chrome on the list item :)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't inspect in chrome since the app won't run without some phonegap specific code